# open front camera using java script on mobile version website

Tags: javascript, html, css

im trying to open camera on mobile version website. the code is working perfectly from pc but not when i access the website from my mobile. the website is published to firebase cloud.

here is the code:

script.js:

```
const video = document.getElementById('video')

Promise.all([
  faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri('/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri('/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri('/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceExpressionNet.loadFromUri('/models')
]).then(startVideo)

function startVideo() {
  navigator.getUserMedia(
    { video: {} },
    stream => video.srcObject = stream,
    err => console.error(err)
  )
}

video.addEventListener('play', () => {
  const canvas = faceapi.createCanvasFromMedia(video)
  document.body.append(canvas)
  const displaySize = { width: video.width, height: video.height }
  faceapi.matchDimensions(canvas, displaySize)
  setInterval(async () => {
    const detections = await faceapi.detectAllFaces(video, new faceapi.TinyFaceDetectorOptions()).withFaceLandmarks().withFaceExpressions()
    const resizedDetections = faceapi.resizeResults(detections, displaySize)
    canvas.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    faceapi.draw.drawDetections(canvas, resizedDetections)
    faceapi.draw.drawFaceLandmarks(canvas, resizedDetections)
    faceapi.draw.drawFaceExpressions(canvas, resizedDetections)
  }, 100)
})
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script defer src="face-api.min.js"></script>
  <script defer src="script.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    canvas {
      position: absolute;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <video id="video" width="720" height="560" autoplay muted></video>
</body>
</html>
```

what i did to try to solve this problem is to change  navigator.getUserMedia to  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia , what happened is that the browser on pc or mobile version is asking for the permission to access the camera but not open anything, just white screen.

any help?

Comment: It seems the navigator.getUserMedia is deprecated. Try to use navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia() . See documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia) the first parameter of navigator.getUserMedia function should be like {video: true}